# Confusion regarding maxSockets option in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a nodejs application, wherein I make API calls to another service.
I am using the request module of nodejs to do this. I have set a value of maxSockets to ensure that more number of concurrent requests can be made to the API.
I have two doubts:
1. For how long does a socket used to make the request keeps the HTTP connection alive?
2. Suppose the number of requests hitting nodejs are less compared to the value of maxSockets option I have set. If a new request would come now, then it would it always use a new Socket establish a new connection for the API call I make. In what scenarios, will it wait to reuse to use an existing socket connection?